# SoapHttpClientProtocol throws NameResolutionFailure, not ProxyNameResolutionFailure

Tags: .net, proxy, system.net.webexception, soaphttpclientprotocol

SoapHttpClientProtocol throws a WebException with status NameResolutionFailure when the proxy name is invalid. How then can I tell if it's the proxy or the destination that is in err?

I'd rather not perform a check if the proxy server exists when a NameResolutionFailure shows up. The only think I can think to do is check the WebException.message property and see if it contains the proxy name vs. the destination name, but this seems icky. Is it the best available?

Comment: Why do you care which is missing? What will you do differently in either case?

Comment: Prompt the user appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the message property, I suppose :/